# How to select folders containing only one CSV file among a large number of folders?

Tags: r, csv, import, directory

I have a large number of folders which contain csv and htm files under each folder (some folders have multiple csv files and some with only one csv file).

Would it be possible to automatically screen and get those folders with only one csv file and import the data into R or other statistical packages?

Comment: If the CVS files you want to read have a common pattern, you can use `list.files` with `pattern` argument

Answer (score 0):

```
getwd()
all_files<-list.files()
split_all_files<-sapply(all_files,function(x) strsplit(x, "\\.")[1])

for(i in seq(1,length(all_files))){

  if(split_all_files[[i]][2]=="csv"){
    data_file<-data.frame()
    data_file<-read.csv(all_files[i])

   }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to search all directories for `csv` files but to consider only those directories which contain *exactly one* `csv` file. Only those files should be imported.

On UNIX systems, there are OS commands like `fgrep` which probably can be used for this purpose but I believe the base R solution below should be working on any system:

```
# define starting dir
path <- file.path("path", "to", "start", "search")
# or path <- file.path(".")
# or path <- getwd()

# find all directories, recursively, i.e., also sub-directories
dirs <- list.dirs(path, recursive = TRUE)

# search all directories for csv files, i.e., file name is ending with csv
# return result as a list with a vector of file names per list element
csv_files <- lapply(dirs, list.files, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

# pick only those list elements which contain exactly one .csv file
# and unlist to get vector of file names.
# note lenghts() gets the length of each element of a list
files_to_read <- unlist(csv_files[lengths(csv_files) == 1L])

# read selected files, return result in a list
imported <- lapply(files_to_read, data.table::fread)
# or use a different file reader, alternatively
imported <- lapply(files_to_read, readr::read_csv)

# name list elements to identify imported data sets
setNames(imported) <- files_to_read
# or use only the file name
setNames(imported) <- basename(files_to_read)
# or use only the name of the enclosing directory
setNames(imported) <- basename(dirname(files_to_read))
```